# Necessary and sufficient conditions for solvability of a linear matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Consider the matrix equation 
$$
A^TUA  + C = U,
$$
in the variable $U$, with $A, C$ given. Above, $A, U, C$ are real matrices of compatible dimensions.

What are necessary and sufficient conditions to ensure that a solution to the above equation exists?

Some observations/facts:

- if the spectral radius $\rho(A) < 1$, then via Gelfand's formula, one verifies the existence of a solution.
- in one dimension, the equation is $c = (1 - a^2) u$. Hence, the equation always has a solution if and only if either $c = 0$ or $|a| \neq 1$.

Can we generalize the second condition? What should it be?

Comment: Related: [algebraic Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation) and [discrete Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ has a full set of left eigenvectors, then with
$L(U) = A^TU A -U$, we have
$L(u_i u_j^T) = (\lambda_i \lambda_j -1) u_i u_j^T$, so we see that $L$ has eigenvalues
$\lambda_i \lambda_j -1$.

The general result follows from continuity.

So, to (partially) answer your question, $L(U)=-C$ has a unique solution for all $C$ **iff** $\lambda_i\lambda_j \neq 1$ for all $i,j$.

More generally, a (not necessarily unique) solution exists **iff** $C$ is in the range of $L$.

Comment: The uniqueness answer is interesting. Can you expand a bit on how you arrive at the eigenvalues of the Lyapunov map are $\{\lambda_i \lambda_j - 1\}$? I agree that by letting $u_i$ denote the completion of the left eigenbasis of $A$, we arrive at $L(u_iu_j^T) = (\lambda_i \lambda_j - 1)u_iu_j^T$. And also $u_i u_j^T$ span $\mathbf{R}^{n \times m}$; so do we not see immediately that the $nm$ eigenvalues are a subset of $\{\lambda_i \lambda_j - 1\}$ (also I believe there is a typo in your first sentence?) I also do not see why the continuity part is needed.

Comment: It follows from the equation $L(u_i u_j^T) = (\lambda_i \lambda_i -1) u_i u_j^T$ since the $u_i u_j^T$ are a basis. Essentially, if $A$ is diagonalisable then so is $L$.

Comment: Ah I see; so you are saying the continuity is needed when $A$ is not diagonalizable.   (Sorry I was assuming $A = A^T$, which is certainly not the case in general.)

Comment: Well, strictly speaking not necessary, but the proof is quick using a continuity argument.